# Do constructor( that we code ) replaces the default constructor?

Tags: java, class, constructor

```
public class A {
  int i;
  int j;

  A() {
    i = 3; // I have not intialized j;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new A();
    // Why obj.j is printed if my constructor had initialized int j?
    System.out.println(obj.i + obj.j); 
  }
}
```

if our coded constructor replaces the default constructor then how the reference values that I had not initialized in my constructor get default values

Comment: Uninitialized fields get default values. The constructor doesn't need to set them.

Comment: "Why obj.j is printed" you're not printing `obj.j` directly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instance variables have default values, regardless of whether any constructor initializes them. All numeric primitive instance variables have a default value of 0, which is the value of `j` in your code (even though you haven't initialized it).

Comment: Then why java had default Constructors?

Comment: @AdarshChaubey One of reasons is that `super(..)` must be called somewhere, and that place is specified to be constructor (explicit or implicit one).